# Attempting to install version '5.0.0' of 'EntityFramework' but the project already includes a different version

Tags: .net, entity-framework, error-handling, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

When I add code generation item I get this error:

> Attempting to install version '5.0.0'  of 'EntityFramework' but the
>   project already  includes a different version. Skipping...

How I can fix it?

Comment: What version is already installed. Was it installed with nuget? If, so have you tried unistalling it using `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework` from package manager console?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to execute commands [in package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console), i hope it help you:

> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force

it force uninstall package with dependencies
and after uninstalling execute:

> Install-Package EntityFramework

Comment: Yeah! It helps. It says: `Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0-rc'.` and after this `Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.` So the `RC` is the problem. Thanks man!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, after reading a lot of other answers this simple couple of steps actually worked for me.

```
PM> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
Removing 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' from XXXXX.
Successfully removed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' from XXXXX.
Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
Installing 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
You are downloading EntityFramework from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is    available at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=253898&clcid=0x409. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'.
Adding 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to XXXXX.
Successfully added 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to XXXXX.
```

Before this I had tried the following but without success:
1. Removed the existing reference to EntityFramework, but couldn't add a new reference. 
2. Researched if EntityFramework needs to downloaded and installed differently.

Thankfully I didn't follow some other posts about installing the CTP 5. I already have .net 4.5 and VS Express for the web installed. No other installation was required.

Disclaimer: I am a beginner, so my answer may not be entirely correct.